# Redirect different user profiles to different pages?

Tags: django, web-applications, backend

How can "http://my-domain.com/users" return a unique profile page for each user?

Comment: Why do you think they're *"different pages"*, rather than the same page with *different data*?

Comment: What's the actual question here? "Redirect user profiles to pages"? Don't get it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: ok, they should be handled by a single page. I get it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`RedirectView` in Django is normal view. It can take parameters from URL dispatcher, do some logic and decide where to redirect, based on that parameters (or even something more).

New URL can be fetched from database, built using parameters from dispatcher or even randomized.

You can also use old, function based view and simply return `HttpResponseRedirect`.